# MATLAB: Confusing behavior with containers.Map

Tags: matlab

I'm having some trouble accessing the value using a particular key (I'm using containers.Map).  I've set up a Map called `team_dict` that looks something like:

```
{ 'Columbia' : 'www.columbia.com', 'Bates' : 'www.bates.com', ... }
```

I try to do

```
url = team_dict(currentKey);
```

to access the value in the Map corresponding to the key currentKey.

Here's the relevant code:

```
allKeys = keys(team_dict);

%loop through all keys
for i = 1 : length(allKeys)
    %for current key (team name), getTeam
    currentKey = allKeys(i);
    disp(currentKey);
    url = team_dict(currentKey);
end
```

I get this error:

```
Error using containers.Map/subsref
Specified key type does not match the type expected for this container.

Error in project (line 27)
    teamPlayers = getTeam(team_dict(currentKey), currentKey);
```

The strange thing is that 'Columbia' prints out correctly when I call `disp(currentKey)`.  Also, in the interactive prompt, when I do

```
team_dict('Columbia')
```

I get back the correct URL.

Any idea why this is happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `allKeys = keys(team_dict);` returns a cell array of keys, when you get `currentKey = allKeys(i);` you will have a cell containing the key.

Since your keys are all string, `disp(currentKey);` still works. But `url = team_dict(currentKey);` will result in error since `currentKey` is now a cell of string.

What you have to do is just modification this line:

```
currentKey = allKeys(i);
```

to

```
currentKey = allKeys{i};
```

Comment: Do you mind elaborating on the diff between {} and [] or pointing me in the direction of more info on it?  Ignore, just found: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/what-is-a-cell-array.html

Comment: Yes, that is the link. If your question is resolved, do you mind accepting the answer?